# d3.js visualization with pyqt

Tags: d3.js, pyqt5

I am trying to find the best visualization library for my predictive model. i am aware of matplotlib, bokeh libraries for visualization purpose, but Is there any support for making use of d3.js to use as a visualization library with PyQt, if yes please let me know any documentation of it.

Comment: I guess you could use d3.js inside a `QWebEngineView`.

Comment: ok thanks for that information.